# passing slice as a reference to reflect changes in caller

Tags: arrays, go, append, slice

main declares a slice with name `allOutputs` (i believe its a slice of strings, not an array of strings) with zero length and 100 capacity. Then it appends a string with value "abcd" and calls myTest function which updates the array[0] with "1234" and then does an append with value "5678".

When i printed `allOutputs` after `myTest` call, i correctly see the element at the first index has an updated value of "1234". This tells me that myTest got slice as reference. But the later `append` of `"5678"` is not seen by the caller (main here) at all why its so? Remember the original slice is backed by an array with a capacity of 100. Why can't i see 5678 in main when the slice is passed by a reference?

In other words, how exactly the append works?

```
import "fmt"

func myTest(array []string) {
    array[0] = "1234"
    array = append(array, "5678")
}

func main() {
    allOutputs := make([]string, 0, 100)
    allOutputs = append(allOutput, "abcd")
        fmt.Println(allOutputs) // Println1
    myTest(allOutputs)
    fmt.Println(allOutputs) // Println2
}
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT:
[1234]

I EXPECTED:
[1234, 5678]

Comment: There is no “pass by reference”, so I’m not sure where you got that. You’re simply passing the slice value, which which is a copy and not going to change the original.

Comment: When you pass a slice, Go passes a copy of the slice header. That explains why array[0] = "1234". You can still access and alert the underlay array objects. On the other hand append creates a copy of the slice and the underlaying array and because the `myTest` function doesn't return it, you don't see the  changes in `main`. When I started looking at slices I found https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks very useful.

Answer (score 0):

`append` works exactly as you think it does!

As you can see in [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fj2D6NLI_ag), the `append` function works as you're expecting if you don't pass the `allOutputs` array as a parameter to `myTest`.

As you suspected, `append` **may** return a new array if the capacity of the original array is exceeded. In your example, the array size in `myTest` is **not** modified, however, it is a copy of `allOutputs` which remains unchanged.

It's best to think of an array like a string. It's a mutable block of memory. When passed as a parameter, the whole block is copied.

Your assumption that, because the array `allOutputs` is pre-allocated with 100 elements the call to `append` won't need to change `array`, is correct.

If you'd written *this*, you would have seen the results you expected.

```
allOutputs := make([]string, 0, 100)
allOutputs = append(allOutputs, "abcd")
fmt.Println(allOutputs) // Println1
allOutputs[0] = "1234"
allOutputs = append(allOutputs, "5678")
fmt.Println(allOutputs) // Println2
```

One nice solution to this is:

```
   type myStrings []string

   func (m *mystring) myTest() {
      // Do something
   }
```

If you declare your own type, then you can define a method that can mutate the array without explicitly using the & operator.